# What is the left panel called in mxGraph?

Tags: java, gui

I am working on a network graph simulator using [mxGraph](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph) and java. The problem is that I want to remove the left panel from the [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im4ED.png). There is a option to hide/show but I wanted it hidden as default. And I can not figure out what is this panel called. SO, I do not which code I have to *comment out* or which variable to make it *false*. I am new to **mxGraph**, so it would be helpful if anyone have any suggestion for how to remove the left panel is very much appreciated.

Comment: Post that as an answer, not a comment. In a day or so you'll be able to mark it as the correct answer and others trying to do the same thing will see it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the portion of the code to change. There are two *JSplitPane* one for *VERTiCAL SPLIT* and *HORIZONTAL SPLIT*. So i just have to make the `Visibility = false`